# Is it possible to set maxtasksperchild for a threadpool?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

After encountering some probable memory leaks in a long running multi threaded script I found out about `maxtasksperchild`, which can be used in a Multi process pool like this:

```
import multiprocessing

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=32, maxtasksperchild=x) as pool:
    pool.imap(function,stuff)
```

Is something similar possible for the Threadpool (`multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the answer by [noxdafox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56215980/7454706) said, there is no way in the parent class, you can use `threading` module to control the max number of tasks per child. As you want to use `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool`, `threading` module is similar, so...

```
def split_processing(yourlist, num_splits=4):
    '''
    yourlist = list which you want to pass to function for threading.
    num_splits = control total units passed.
    '''
    split_size = len(yourlist) // num_splits
    threads = []
    for i in range(num_splits):
        start = i * split_size
        end = len(yourlist) if i+1 == num_splits else (i+1) * split_size
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=function, args=(yourlist, start, end)))
        threads[-1].start()

    # wait for all threads to finish
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Lets say
yourlist has 100 items, then

```
if num_splits = 10; then threads = 10, each thread has 10 tasks.
if num_splits = 5; then threads = 5, each thread has 20 tasks.
if num_splits = 50; then threads = 50, each thread has 2 tasks.
and vice versa.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` [implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L921) it becomes evident that the `maxtaskperchild` parameter is not propagated to the parent `multiprocessing.Pool` class. The `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` implementation has never been completed, hence it lacks few features (as well as tests and documentation).

The [pebble](https://pypi.org/project/Pebble/) package implements a [`ThreadPool`](https://pebble.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pebble.ThreadPool) which supports workers restart after a given amount of tasks have been processed.

Comment: Thx for your answer, I did indeed look into the code and also tried to write my own sublcass of the ThreadPool, that did not work unfortunately. Is pebble reliable?

Comment: You cannot easily subclass the `ThreadPool` as the inner logic to make certain features work is stripped away (`_wrap_exception` for example). For a library adoption, you can use `pypistats` for the download count or the GitHub dependency graph to measure how much is spread. From there, you can get an idea of its reliability. Other than that, you need to test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted a ThreadPool that will run a new task as soon as another task in the pool completes (i.e. `maxtasksperchild=1`). I decided to write a small "ThreadPool" class that creates a new thread for every task. As soon a task in the pool completes, another thread is created for the next value in the iterable passed to the `map` method. The `map` method blocks until all values in the passed iterable have been processed and their threads returned.

```
import threading


class ThreadPool():

    def __init__(self, processes=20):
        self.processes = processes
        self.threads = [Thread() for _ in range(0, processes)]

    def get_dead_threads(self):
        dead = []
        for thread in self.threads:
            if not thread.is_alive():
                dead.append(thread)
        return dead

    def is_thread_running(self):
        return len(self.get_dead_threads()) < self.processes

    def map(self, func, values):
        attempted_count = 0
        values_iter = iter(values)
        # loop until all values have been attempted to be processed and
        # all threads are finished running
        while (attempted_count < len(values) or self.is_thread_running()):
            for thread in self.get_dead_threads():
                try:
                    # run thread with the next value
                    value = next(values_iter)
                    attempted_count += 1
                    thread.run(func, value)
                except StopIteration:
                    break

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        pass


class Thread():

    def __init__(self):
        self.thread = None

    def run(self, target, *args, **kwargs):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=target,
                                       args=args,
                                       kwargs=kwargs)
        self.thread.start()

    def is_alive(self):
        if self.thread:
            return self.thread.is_alive()
        else:
            return False
```

You can use it like this:

```
def run_job(self, value, mp_queue=None):
    # do something with value
    value += 1


with ThreadPool(processes=2) as pool:
    pool.map(run_job, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```